# Using CircularProgressIndicator widget while loading images from Firebase in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, spinner

I want to know how I can add circularprogressindicator to images which I getting from firebase. When I load data 'texts' come first then images and it seems not elegant. Here is my code. Please review my code and help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'Myapp_screen';
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('news').limit(20).snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                value: null,
                strokeWidth: 2.0,
              ));
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                  snapshot.data.documents[index];
                  return Container(
                    child: Card(
                      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                        Image.network(documentSnapshot['images']),
                        Text(documentSnapshot['title'])
                      ]),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use loading builder property to achieve so.

Following code clear your idea.

```
Image.network(
          'https://previews.123rf.com/images/blueringmedia/blueringmedia1701/blueringmedia170100692/69125003-colorful-kite-flying-in-blue-sky-illustration.jpg',
          loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
              ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
            if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                    ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                        loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes
                    : null,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Dear Viren. Thanks for your comment and intention to help. Yes it is worked but I don't know if it is because your code or here is another reason but list doesn't work smooth. I can scroll down very slow. Do you have any opinion about this issue.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think it is because of images. Moreover if you are testing in emulator then it could be more laggy. I think I will be fine in real device and in release mode.

Comment: Unfortunately in real device it is lagging but in simulator everything works fine

Comment: It is really strange try in release mode.

Comment: Great solution! Works even better with LinearProgressIndicator.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a gif or any other loading animation asset you can use the following code that makes use of the `FadeInImage()` function.

```
FadeInImage(
  placeholder: AssetImage('assets/LOADING_ANIMATION.gif'),
  image: NetworkImage('URL_OF_IMAGE'),
)
```

So the full code would look like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'Myapp_screen';
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('news').limit(20).snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                value: null,
                strokeWidth: 2.0,
              ));
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                  snapshot.data.documents[index];
                  return Container(
                    child: Card(
                      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                        FadeInImage(
                          placeholder: AssetImage('assets/LOADING_ANIMATION.gif'),
                          image: NetworkImage(documentSnapshot['images']),
                        ),
                        Text(documentSnapshot['title'])
                      ]),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Fade in images';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            Center(
              child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                image: 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did all the steps as you indicated here but spinner works in the background and doesn't disappear. Is there any solutions for that?

Comment: Glad it worked. Please mark the answer as 'accepted' so that others can be befitted as well.

Comment: Dear friend yes its worked but as I said in my previous comment spinner spins constantly and doesn't stop.

Comment: yes but as per your this question to show loader in image of listview is satisfy. create new  question for that.